# Using labels in Batch import

Tags: neo4j

In the new 2.0 branch of the NEO4J [batch-importer](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/tree/20),

To specify a label, I believe one must specify the header, 
Using the example from the readme.md and wiki:

```
name    l:label       age works_on
Michael Person,Father 37  neo4j
Selina  Person,Child  14
Rana    Person,Child  6
Selma   Person,Child  4
```

Does the header always have to follow the following format of being `l:label` and 
What does the comma do and is it optional? 
ie. What does `person,Father` represent? `label,???`

I believe in this case `Person` is the label but I'm curious how can I query (in cypher) the label value in this case either `Father` or `Child`.

Comment: Realised the `,` is to add different labels to the nodes.

Comment: Do you still have a question about querying with Cypher or did figuring out the `,` solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you wanted to explicitly assign the type of some property you would use colon + type for that, i.e.

```
name:String age:int
```

and `:label` is used after the fashion of a data type to signal that the value(s) in a field is a node label or a relationship type. Since labels are not name/value pairs like properties, I would think the `l` in `l:label` doesn't really do anything.